# Grails Views Pagination output not rendering next and last links

Tags: grails, pagination, grails3

In the Grails JSON Views documentation

http://views.grails.org/latest/#_json_api_support

2.10.5 Pagination

Since I was leaving the max as the default and I have a total of 40+ rows of data in my database, the first next and last links didn't render as what it's shown in the example below:

```
"links": {
  "self": "/books",
  "first": "http://localhost:8080/books?offset=0&max=10",
  "next": "http://localhost:8080/books?offset=10&max=10",
  "last": "http://localhost:8080/books?offset=10&max=10"
}
```

Did I miss anything? Thanks.

Comment: Offset will be 1 and 2 for 'next' and 'last' respectively.

Comment: How did they render? You haven't explained the problem